# How to calculate difference between two sets in emacs lisp,the sets should be lists

Tags: lisp, elisp, set, set-difference

How to calculate the difference between two sets in Emacs Lisp? The sets should be lists.
The programm should be very simple and short, or else I won't understand it. I'm a newbee.

Thx

Answer (score 10):

There is a `set-difference` function in the Common Lisp extensions:

```
elisp> (require 'cl-lib)
cl-lib
elisp> (cl-set-difference '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4))
(1)
```

Comment: These days, require 'cl-lib instead of the deprecated 'cl, and namespace the function as `cl-set-difference`.

Answer (score 6):

When I write Elisp code that has lots of list data transformations, I use [`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) library, because it has loads of functions to work with lists. Set difference can be done with [`-difference`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-difference-list-list2):

```
(require 'dash)
(-difference '(1 2 3 4) '(3 4 5 6)) ;; => '(1 2)
```

Comment: You might also be looking for the difference of the _union_ and _intersection_ of two sets: `(let ((a '(1 2 3 4)) (b '(3 4 5 6))) (-difference (-union a b) (-intersection a b))) ;; => '(1 2 5 6)`

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: this is not an efficient way to do it in eLisp. An efficient way is through a hash-table with a hash function, but since you asked about lists, then here it is:

```
(defun custom-set-difference (a b)
  (remove-if
     #'(lambda (x) (and (member x a) (member x b)))
     (append a b)))

(custom-set-difference '(1 2 3 4 5) '(2 4 6))

(1 3 5 6)

(defun another-set-difference (a b)
  (if (null a) b
    (let (removed)
      (labels ((find-and-remove
                (c)
                (cond
                 ((null c) nil)
                 ((equal (car c) (car a))
                  (setq removed t) (cdr c))
                 (t (cons (car c) (find-and-remove (cdr c)))))))
        (setf b (find-and-remove b))
        (if removed
            (another-set-difference (cdr a) b)
          (cons (car a) (another-set-difference (cdr a) b)))))))

(another-set-difference '(1 2 3 4 5) '(2 4 6))

(1 3 5 6)
```

The second is slightly more efficient, because it will remove the elements as it makes consequent checks, but the first is shorter and more straight-forward.

Also note that lists are not good representation of sets because they naturally allow repetition. Hash maps are better for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple & short definition, which should be easy to understand. It is essentially the same as the `set-difference` function in the Common Lisp library for Emacs, but without any treatment of a TEST argument.

```
(defun set-diff (list1 list2 &optional key)
  "Combine LIST1 and LIST2 using a set-difference operation.
Optional arg KEY is a function used to extract the part of each list
item to compare.

The result list contains all items that appear in LIST1 but not LIST2.
This is non-destructive; it makes a copy of the data if necessary, to
avoid corrupting the original LIST1 and LIST2."
  (if (or (null list1)  (null list2))
      list1
    (let ((keyed-list2  (and key  (mapcar key list2)))
          (result       ()))
      (while list1
        (unless (if key
                    (member (funcall key (car list1)) keyed-list2)
                  (member (car list1) list2))
          (setq result  (cons (car list1) result)))
        (setq list1  (cdr list1)))
      result)))
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual, [Sets and Lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sets-And-Lists.html) suggests using *cl-lib*'s
 **cl-set-difference** *LIST1* *LIST2* `&key :test :test-not :key`

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-set-difference '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4))
(1)
```