# How to delete a list of elements from another list in ELisp?

Tags: list, emacs, elisp

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-local ac-sources
                        (delq '(ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers) ac-sources))))
```

I found here `delq` only can delete element from list, it can't delete a list from another list. neither `delete`.

So how to archive my effect.

Comment: I am surprised by the statement that `delete` does not delete a list from a list. In my emacs scratch buffer the result of `(delete '(first 2) '(first 2 (first 2) third 4))` is
`(first 2 third 4)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `delq` in a loop:

```lisp
(mapcar (lambda (x) (setq ac-sources (delq x ac-sources)))
        '(ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
```

Comment: Probably better to use `mapc` if you don't require `mapcar`'s accumulated result.

Comment: Sure, why not. I was surprised that I had to use `setq`. Do you know why a plain `delq` doesn't work?

Comment: @abo-abo The variable points to the first cons cell in the list, which stores the first list element.  If `delq` drops that element and its cons cell, the variable still holds the *old* cons cell.

Comment: Oh, I see, this help me, I did some test with (1 2 3) and ((1 2 3) 4 5 6). I wander why (1 2 3) can't be delete. Now I see.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is called [`cl-set-difference`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Lists-as-Sets.html):

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq-local ac-sources
                (cl-set-difference 
                 ac-sources
                 '(ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers)))))
```

See also [How to calculate difference between two sets in emacs lisp,the sets should be lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939855/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-sets-in-emacs-lisp-the-sets-should-be-li).